# pandas.errors.MergeError Not allowed to merge between different levels

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble joining two datasets

```
data = races_df.join(runs_df, on='race_id', how='right')
X = data[data.columns[:-14]]
ss = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X = pd.DataFrame(ss.fit_transform(X),columns = X.columns)
y_won = data[data.columns[-14:]].applymap(lambda x: 1.0 if 0.5 < x < 1.5 else 0.0)
    
print(X.shape)
print(y_won.shape)
```

when i run the code i get error message

```
pandas.errors.MergeError: Not allowed to merge between different levels. 
   (1 levels on the left, 2 on the right)
```

Does anyone know the correct code that wont produce this error thx

Comment: What is `print (races_df.info())` and  `print (runs_df.info())` ?

Comment: thats is just the database i print them as i go to check

Answer (score 0):

In second `DataFrame` is `MultiIndex`, so is possible remove first or second level, depends of data:

```
data = t1_df.join(t2_df.droplevel(0), on='race_id')
data = t1_df.join(t2_df.droplevel(1), on='race_id')
```

Or convert it to column:

```
data = t1_df.join(t2_df.reset_index(0), on='race_id')
data = t1_df.join(t2_df.reset_index(1), on='race_id')
```

Comment: Thx Jezreal  for your quick responses i really appreciate it :)  I'm still getting a error but it now says ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.

Comment: @user3060111 What is `print (races_df.info())` and `print (runs_df.info())` ?

Comment: @user3060111 - I guess need `data = t1_df.join(t2_df.droplevel(0, axis=1), on='race_id')` or `data = t1_df.join(t2_df.droplevel(1, axis=1), on='race_id')`